# Change single quotes to double quotes by Regular expression. (in single words)

Tags: javascript, regex

I tring to change single quotes to double quotes in text by Regular expression. (in single words)
**EXAMPLE:** I'm go. You gona fly to planet 'Ziqtos'  **=>** I need to keep single quotes in **I'm**, and change to double in You gona fly **"Ziqtos"** Please help.
There is my code.

```
    var myStr = "I, I can't deny I'm paralysed from the 'inside' Everyday I wake to feel the same And 'every' time you 'ask' me how I'm feeling I just smile and tell you 'that' I'm fine I, I don't know why I'm terrified of everything Just to call the doctor seems daunting For most of my life I felt a sharp uncertainty Now its just become a part of me I, I can't deny I'm paralysed from the inside Everyday I wake to feel the 'same' And every time you ask me how I'm feeling I just smile and tell you that I'm fine It's hard to stay true, to myself and to you I can't measure up to this girl you thought you knew This aching in my heart is tearing me apart But, darling all your love is somehow not 'enough' This aching in my heart is tearing me apart But, darling all your love is somehow not"

    var newStr = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < myStr.length; i++) {
        var lastIndex = myStr.search(/\s'[a-zA-Z]/ || /[a-zA-Z]'\s/);
        newStr += myStr.substr(0, lastIndex + 1);
        newStr += '\"';
        myStr = myStr.substr(lastIndex + 2);
    }

    var Phar = document.createElement("p");
    Phar.innerHTML = newStr;
    document.body.appendChild(Phar);
```

Comment: How about you add word boundaries (left or right, two options) to the single-quote character you want to match. This eliminates the "I'm" issue - but leaves the issue of apostrophes at word end (not part of your examples), e.g. "Mr. Jones’ golf clubs".

Comment: How does one know whether the single-quotes should be changed to double-quotes or not? What rules **specifically** keep `I'm go` as a single-quote and `You gona fly to planet 'Ziqtos'` as **double**-quotes?

Comment: [`.replace(/(?!\b'\b)'/g, '"')`](https://regex101.com/r/9zK5sk/1)

Comment: There is short unswer below. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/RG8rsb/2)

```
\B'|'\B
```

Alternatively, you can use `\B'(\w+)'\B` and replace with `"$1"`

#### Usage

```js
const regex = /\B'|'\B/g;
const str = `I'm go. You gona fly to planet 'Ziqtos'`;
const str2 = `I, I can't deny I'm paralysed from the 'inside' Everyday I wake to feel the same And 'every' time you 'ask' me how I'm feeling I just smile and tell you 'that' I'm fine I, I don't know why I'm terrified of everything Just to call the doctor seems daunting For most of my life I felt a sharp uncertainty Now its just become a part of me I, I can't deny I'm paralysed from the inside Everyday I wake to feel the 'same' And every time you ask me how I'm feeling I just smile and tell you that I'm fine It's hard to stay true, to myself and to you I can't measure up to this girl you thought you knew This aching in my heart is tearing me apart But, darling all your love is somehow not 'enough' This aching in my heart is tearing me apart But, darling all your love is somehow not`;
const subst = `"`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);
const result2 = str2.replace(regex, subst);

console.log(result);
console.log(result2);
```

---

### Results

**Input**

```
I'm go. You gona fly to planet 'Ziqtos'
```

**Output**

```
I'm go. You gona fly to planet "Ziqtos"
```

---

### Explanation

- `\B` Assert position where `\b` does not match
- `'` Match the apostrophe character literally

Comment: Output: I, " "an"t de"y I'm pa"al"se" "ro" "he"'"ns"de" "ve"yd"y I wa"e to"fe"l th" "am" "nd"'"ve"y' "im" "ou"'"sk" "e ho" "'" "ee"in" " "us" "mi"e an" "el" "ou"'"ha"'"I'm fi"e I, " "on"t kn"w wh" "'" "er"if"ed"of"ev"ry"hi"g Ju"t to"ca"l th"..............

Comment: _Have to be like this:_ I, I **can't** deny **I'm** paralysed from the **"inside"** Everyday I wake to...

Comment: @Pavel please take a look at the sample code above.

Comment: WOW! I killed almost half day on it. THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

in your scenario you can get away with this regex `/\'(\w+)\'/g`:

```js
var myStr = "I, I can't deny I'm paralysed from the 'inside' Everyday I wake to feel the same And 'every' time you 'ask' me how I'm feeling I just smile and tell you 'that' I'm fine I, I don't know why I'm terrified of everything Just to call the doctor seems daunting For most of my life I felt a sharp uncertainty Now its just become a part of me I, I can't deny I'm paralysed from the inside Everyday I wake to feel the 'same' And every time you ask me how I'm feeling I just smile and tell you that I'm fine It's hard to stay true, to myself and to you I can't measure up to this girl you thought you knew This aching in my heart is tearing me apart But, darling all your love is somehow not 'enough' This aching in my heart is tearing me apart But, darling all your love is somehow not"
    
var txt = myStr.replace(/\'(\w+)\'/g, (_,m) =>
  '"' + m + '"'
  )
  
document.querySelector('div').textContent= txt
```

```html
<div>
```

this will work as long as you want to change the quotes to single words.